# Toeplitz Matrix

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, toeplitz-matrices

Let A be a non-negative Toeplitz matrix, i.e.  $a_{nk}$ >= 0 for all n,k. If $A_n(x)$= $\sum_{n} a_{nk}x_n$, where x is real, prove that

$$\liminf x_n \le \liminf A_n(x) \le \limsup A_n(x) \le \limsup x_n$$

I did not figure out how I can solve this problem, please help!!!!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: thank you. :) :)

Comment: Surely you need some other condition, consider $x_n=1$ and $a_{n,k}=0$. Also $A_n(x)$ as written makes no sense, I am guessing you meant $\sum_k a_{n,k} x_k$.

Comment: I dont know how to use this website, I just applied now. Sorry to my mistakes. Can you type how can ı solve  this question :/